# Lookup function error in SSRS with operators

Tags: reporting-services

```
=Lookup(Fields!ID.Value+Fields!Name.Value+Fields!Age.Value,Fields!ID.Value+Fields!Name.Value+Fields!Age.Value,Fields!Amount.Value,"Table2")

=Lookup(Fields!ID.Value &Fields!Name.Value &Fields!Age.Value,Fields!ID.Value &Fields!Name.Value &Fields!Age.Value,Fields!Amount.Value,"Table2")
```

While using above two expressions in ssrs its displaying error like :

> An Unexpected error occurred while compiling expression. Native
>   compiler returns value: Operator + is not defined for type 'object'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field'.
>
> An Unexpected error occurred while compiling expression. Native
>   compiler returns value: Operator & is not defined for type 'object'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field'.

Please provide a solution to run lookup with multiple columns.

Thanks You.

Answer (score 0):

The first step I would take would be to cast every field value as a string. To do that add`CStr(<Value>)` around every field value. My assumption is that SSRS doesn’t like concatenating numbers and strings.